# Korganizer for windows

Tags: windows

How to I get Korganizer kind of software for windows? Any inputs?

Comment: http://superuser.com/

Comment: @Lakshmi: I think you should post your question to superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news:

[Native Windows version of KOrganizer released as part of Aethera](http://dot.kde.org/2003/08/29/native-windows-version-korganizer-released-part-aethera)

> [korganizer.kde.org](http://korganizer.kde.org/) reports that
>   [theKompany.com](http://www.thekompany.com/home/) recently has
>   released the 1.0 version of their
>   [cross-platform PIM suite Aethera](http://www.thekompany.com/projects/aethera/).
>   This includes KOrganizer as calendar
>   and todo list component. The
>   KOrganizer component is based on the original unmodified
>   KOrganizer source code and has been
>   ported to Windows using a similar
>   technology as was used for porting
>   KOrganizer/Embedded to the Qtopia
>   environment.
>
> [image]
>
> This once again is a
>   great proof of the power and
>   flexibility of open source development
>   and KDE technology.

Comment: This is a really, really, really old version. You almost certainly don't want this. You do, however, want the KDE on Windows installer. That will install KOrganizer for you and all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

[KDE on Windows](http://windows.kde.org/)

> The KDE on Windows Initiative is an ongoing project to port the KDE applications to MS Windows. Currently supported versions of Windows are XP, Vista and 7.
>
> **KDE on Windows is not yet in a final state, so some applications may be unsuitable for everyday use.**

Comment: Uh, I don't think you meant to post a link to this very thread.

Comment: uh, realy i did not.